# Is it possible to run a code only with an environment variable?

Tags: exploit

I'm researching the possibility that modifiable environment variables could have security implications.
I mounted all writable volumes with noexec.
LD_PRELOAD could be an attack surface, but I don't think it will have any effect because of noexec.

Is there anything more to consider in this situation?
If possible, how can code (whether binary or shell script) be injected and executed?

OS is Linux.
Note that, the EnvironmentFile of systemd is used.

Defenced:

- shared-library from directories with noexec set cannot be loaded. So, Attackers cannot use LD_PRELOAD.

systemd service :

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/my-program.sh
EnvironmentFile=/writable-directory/env.txt
```

/my-program.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
some scripts...
openssl...
```

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I also prevented loading shared library inside noexec.

Comment: Isn't what you ask depending on what program you execute? LD_PRELOAD is for the generic program loader only, but programs might use environment variables for a variety of things which lead to attacker controlled code execution. For example PERL5LIB allows you define where Perl is looking for its modules - and it does not care about noexec. Similar with PYTHONPATH etc

Comment: The program I made is a bash script. I don't use ruby/perl, etc. Programs called in the script are all programs written in C (openssl and etc).

Comment: Note that, the EnvironmentFile of systemd is used.

Comment: Please don't add all the relevant information as separate comments - edit your question instead to include every relevant detail. Also, "openssl and etc." is too unspecific - what exactly is "etc."

Comment: Welcome to the community. You mean to inject code from an env variable into an executed code in a bash script or etc?.. It's kind of hard to get what you're exactly asking imho, please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It *used to be* possible to define `bash` functions using environment variables, as this was the method the shell used to pass user-defined functions down to sub-shells (an environment variable with a specific value format). This caused a vulnerability known as [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)), which has been fixed and won't work unless the machine is running an old `bash` version. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233091/bash-functions-in-shell-variables for an example.

As far as I know, there is not currently any way to achieve code execution via environment variables using only the shell. However, there are many programs which allow using environment variables as a substitute for command-line flags or configuration settings in a dotfile. Such programs could be vulnerable to manipulated environment variables, if they have options which cause other programs to be invoked. Similarly, there are some environment variables whose purpose is to identify a common program to execute; perhaps the best known is the `EDITOR` variable, which is used by many different programs to invoke your preferred editor when e.g. creating a `git` commit message; that variable (or others like it, such as `PAGER`) can be set to arbitrary commands and potentially cause those commands to be executed when a different, seemingly-innocuous command (such a `git commit` or `man`) is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few ways in which environment variables can lead to code exec. You mention `LD_PRELOAD` and there is of course `PATH` that could alter which binaries are run.

However **scripting languages aren't affected by noexec**. So a user/attacker could write to `/writable-directory/code_exec.sh` and run `/bin/sh /writable-directory/code_exec.sh` to execute commands of their choosing.

This can be combined with environment variables such as `PERL5OPT`, `PERL5LIB`, `RUBYOPT`, `BASH_FUNC*`, etc to gain code execution on a noexec volume. For examples on how these and other environment variables can lead to code take a look at: https://www.elttam.com/blog/env/#content

Comment: If an attacker can invoke `/bin/sh` with arbitrary arguments at all, it's already game over; the `-c` flag exists, after all, plus most machines will have tools that enable setting up a reverse shell for interactive access. This question makes _no sense_ if you assume the attacker can do that.

Comment: The question lacks enough details not to suggest it can't be done, or that argument injection couldn't occur from a bash script parsing env.txt. I just tried to give a comprehensive answer as the question does specify scripts executing alongside the use of noexec.